# _setmode( _fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY) waits for Enter key when compiled with /MD

Tags: java, c, winapi, java-native-interface, altv

I am embedding a Java VM (JVM) using JNI in a DLL for a native application on Windows (altv-server.exe). Internally JNI_CreateJavaVM calls `_setmode( _fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY )` which causes the process to wait for Enter key input before it continues. The function succeeds but the waiting for input is undesirable.

The mode is in `_O_TEXT` prior to calling `_setmode( _fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY)`.

This behaviour happens when the DLL is built with `/MD`.
With `/MDd`, calling `_setmode` from the DLL will not wait for input, but the function call made from `jvm.dll` still causes the process to wait for input.
The server is built with `/MD`, and so it is required by the DLL to also be built with `/MD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the native application had a thread that was reading from stdin. Calling `_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY)` causes this undesirable behaviour.

Starting that thread after `_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY)` resolved this particular problem.